# NSMatrix deprecated + radioMode .. Alternative

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmatrix

As it appears that NSMatrix is being deprecated soon, I was wondering what a better alternative would be for a column of "NSActionCells" or "NSButtonCells".

NSCollectionView, seems to be one example, but I'm not completely convinced that this is the ultimate way to replace the well-matured NSMatrix.

A good example is a "menu" (vertical or horizontal). NSMAtrix in radioMode was perfect for this.

What would be a good way to replicate this functionality?

Comment: If you watch the latest WWDC videos related to Cocoa, Foundation or AppKit you will probably find the answer to this question (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/). Also, a heads up, they announced in one of those videos that NSCell is on it's way out soon too! Yay!

Comment: Ah perfect! I was wondering which of the lot mentioned it :)